# how to start ubuntu after installation (no choice: only windows starts)

Tags: dual-boot

After testing ubuntu on a usb stick i installed it alongside Windows, no problems thusfar.
BUT, after restarting I did not get the screen giving me the choice between ubuntu and windows, only windows started up immediately.
Hitting esc, F2, F12 and/or del during start up did not help at all.
I am using windows 7 on a Sony Vaio "P".

I would appreciate all help and advice because ubuntu looks really good. Many thanks.

Comment: boot from your live usb and try to reinstall grub

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair is the solution.

Boot linux from live USB.

Install boot repair; open a terminal and follow the below instructions...

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

Run boot repair by typing the following...

sudo boot-repair

Click on "Recommended repair"

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair from live USB. But with running all the following commands at once. That worked for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; 
sudo apt-get update; 
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```